# deSitter spacetime metric and curvature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, de-sitter-spacetime

I have to compute the metric of an hyperboloid given by $-(X^0)^2+(X^1)^2+(X^2)^2+(X^3)^2=H^{-2}$ in 5D Minkowski spacetime using the following coordinates:
$$X^0=H^{-1}\sinh(Ht)\sqrt{1-H^2r^2}$$
$$X^i=x^i \quad\quad i=1,2,3\quad\quad r^2=\sum_i (x^i)^2$$
$$X^4=H^{-1}\cosh(Ht)\sqrt{1-H^2r^2}$$
So I found the metric
$$ds^2=-(1-H^2r^2)dt^2+\frac{H^2}{1-H^2r^2}r^2dr^2+\sum_i(dx^i)^2$$
Now I should find the vielbiens to compute the curvature, the first is easy $e^o=\sqrt{1-H^2r^2}$, but I can't find the others.
Some hint?

Comment: Take note that $(x^i)^2 = r^2$ and $x^i \, dx^i \equiv r \, dr$, so you could simplify your metric alot!  The last complicated part could be simplified.  What is the $\Sigma$ in the second term?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is the sum over i

Comment: I edited the metric with the simplification suggested but stil cant fix in vielbiens the last term

Comment: It still can be simplified again!  The last term is $dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 = dr^2 + r^2 \, d\Omega^2$.  It simplifies the second term.

Comment: @Pancio Please use the `\sum` command instead of `\Sigma` when you mean a sum.